# Mongo DB collections are not found

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am using MongoDB as my data storage, version v3.4.1. I am using a docker image of mongo, running it like this:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v /home/rancher/data:/data/db --name mongodb mongo:latest
```

After that I created many databases and collections. It was fine for more than one month; but now I am not able to find any collections inside the data base. This command to list collections is showing an empty list: `show dbs`. Alternatively, if I do `use mydb` then `show collections` nothing is displayed.

These are the data in the /home/rancher/data folder:

> collection-0-‌​-4220404477553112134‌​.wt
>   collection-0-1041804628168690390.w‌​t
>   collection-2--4220404477553112134.wt
>   collection-2-1041804628168690390.wt
>   diagnostic.data
>   index-1--4220404477553112134.wt
>   index-1-1041804628168690390.wt
>   index-3--4220404477553112134.wt
>   index-3-1041804628168690390.wt
>   index-4-1041804628168690390.wt
>   journal
>   _mdb_catalog.wt
>   mongod.lock
>   sizeStorer.wt
>   storage.bson
>   WiredTiger
>   WiredTiger.lock
>   WiredTiger.turtle
>   WiredTiger.wt
>   WiredTigerLAS.wt

Can anyone tell me why the collections are not persistent in mongo DB?

Comment: When you look in the location 'home/rancher/data' on the host, does it contain any data files at all?

Comment: Can you describe exactly how you can't find any collections? Do they not show up in the list given by _show collections_ in the mongo shell - or is it something else?

Comment: @VinceBowdren, These are the data in the /home/rancher/data folder
WiredTiger, _mdb_catalog.wt, diagnostic.data, index-4-1041804628168690390.wt,WiredTiger.lock,collection-0--4220404477553112134.wt  index-1--4220404477553112134.wt       journal,WiredTiger.turtle,collection-0-1041804628168690390.wt   index-1-1041804628168690390.wt, mongod.lock,WiredTiger.wt                         collection-2--4220404477553112134.wt, index-3--4220404477553112134.wt,  sizeStorer.wt,WiredTigerLAS.wt                      collection-2-1041804628168690390.wt,  index-3-1041804628168690390.wt, storage.bson

Comment: once i created the collection it will vanish after few days. so I am not able to proceed with my tasks.
when I am doing this command to list collection its showing empty list
show dbs
then use mydb
show collections
nothing will display here

can you help to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. This is the solution I found. Please check your mongodb port is open to the internet. if so restrict it to the servers.

Answer (score 0):

you may have ran into a problem with `mongo:latest` tag and how mongodb changed the default driver they used for data files.

it's a bad idea to use `:latest` tag of any image because things change between images, and problems like this can happen.

switch to a previous release, like 3.2, and see if it finds you data

`docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v /home/rancher/data:/data/db --name mongodb mongo:3.2.12`

Comment: with versions also i am facing the same issue. Now I am using the version 3.2.0